# How can I access BrowserView objects in html or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I'm currently working on an ElectronJS app where I create a `browserWindow` object using:

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
```

I then load the contents on `index.html`:

```
window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

Finally, I add a `browserView` object to the page:

```
let view = new BrowserView();
window.addBrowserView(view);
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200 });
view.webContents.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
```

Everything works fine but I am unable to find any information on this window in my dev tools. I would like to be able to reference it in my `HTML` and `CSS` files to attach buttons and style it. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried 
view.openDevTools();

Comment: Do you mean `view.webContents.openDevTools();`? I did but that just displays the html of the content of the `BrowserView` (in this case, the html for google.com). I'm looking to target and style the `BrowserView` itself.

Comment: In my case I have A BrowserWindow loaded with my html representation of my app and inside this I put a webview load with the url of a site. In both case I open the DevTools. If you really want to styled the content of your webview I think you have ton inject css code inside it.